# Is Google's Gmail service for my own domain free? I thought it was $50 per domain?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Google Apps could not be found](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30735/free-google-apps-could-not-be-found)

Is Google's Gmail service for my own domain free? I thought it was $50 per domain.

I want to use it for my custom domain's email server, to both send and receive email from a web application.

[This page](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/features.html) says $50 per user, but someone mentioned it was free.

Answer (score 10):

The standard edition of Google Apps is $5/user/month (or $50/user/year). There is also a version that includes a compliance-friendly archive vault for $10/user/month.

Google used to offer a free edition but no longer accepts new sign-ups for it.

Comment: What is the email storage capacity on a standard account? It only lists a premiere account at 25GB.

Comment: Standard amounts allotted to regular Gmail accounts. Mine shows 7518MB right now.

Comment: Sadly, this answer changed recently.
[Google is retiring the free google apps for under 10 users feature.](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2012/12/changes-to-google-apps-for-businesses.html) Much to the sadness of thrifty (cheap) individuals like me.

Answer (score -1):

Well it seems that FOR ONE USER, there is a workaround for the free version, so it is still available and free, but quite limited.

For more info: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2012/12/google-apps-no-longer-free-for-small.html

or google for "google apps free edition workaround"

Comment: Could you back up your statement with references?